# How to get API with basic authentication in MVC .net core

Tags: .net-core, model-view-controller, basic-authentication

I need to get API from server with basic authentication. I have a username and password to access API which will be used to retrieve data for all the user login accounts but I don't know how to retrieve API from server.

Api account != user accounts

I don't know how to do that. In Google, I saw most of them for register and log in. What I want is to retrieve data with API account.

Comment: what do you mean by get/retrieve API from server, are you calling an API using any endpoint?

Comment: I will use endpoint like routing, but i don't know what to do. I am new to web .net core. What i mean is to get/retrieve the data API and then display it. For example, I have a list of customer rent books. I want to retrieve the list of customer. I have 2 accounts, 1 admin account for manage user and other stuffs; and API account which is used to retrieve API.

Comment: make a call to the method as domainName/controlleranme/methodaName. Put userName & password in headers.